# How to tunnel to host using ssh config?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

#### Command I'm using to tunnel:

`ssh -L port:url:port username@hostname`

#### Can I define this in my ssh config? something like this pseudo code:

```
host web
  user 
  url
  hostname
  externalPort
  destinationPort
  tunnel yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be done. For exaple:

```
Host web
  User user_on_web
  DynamicForward localhost:8090
  LocalForward 8070 localhost:8070
  LocalForward 8060 localhost:8060
```

As soon as you ssh into `web`, the tunnels are created. And you get an error that the forwardings already exist, when you open two session into `web`.

`man ssh_config` for more information.

Comment: would I replace local host with the url?

Comment: Yes, -L is LocalForward in the config (-R is RemoteForward in the config). The syntax is slightly different from the commandline, but basically, you're right. Instead of localhost, you configure the target-host you need (you configure a hostname, not a URL, as far as I know).

Comment: Well it's kind of a url, in that you can access it at work on a VM, but yes it does look much more like a host name. Thank you for the help. Also These are rundeck servers which we deploy and then destroy, so things like the hostname and ports change... I'm probably better off writing a function aren't I?